# Ember-leaflet-draw onClick event

Tags: javascript, ember.js, leaflet

onClick event inside ember-leaflet-draw is not working, i called an action onClick and console logged something but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
 {{draw-control position="topright" showDrawingLayer=true 
 enableEditing=true drawingFinishedAction='handleDrawingFinishedAction' 
  addHooks=true onClick=(action 'clicked')}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used this addon. but by looking at the [code](https://github.com/transitland/ember-leaflet-draw/blob/b96dbeaf183c75cff0122d405b9b98c5debdffd0/addon/components/draw-control.js) I can say these are the supported events,

```
leafletEvents: [
    'draw:editstart',
    'draw:editmove',
    'draw:editvertex',
    'draw:editstop',
    'draw:edited'
  ],
```

By defualt `draw-control` component will trigger `drawEditstart`, `drawEditmove`, `drawEditvertex`, `drawEditstop`, `drawEdited` these events alone. so if you send action name while including the component then your action will be called. for eg., if you want to call action on `editstart` then,

```
{{draw-control position="topright" showDrawingLayer=true 
 enableEditing=true drawingFinishedAction='handleDrawingFinishedAction' 
  addHooks=true drawEditstart='drawEditstart'}}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the info and i also after looking into the docs for hours found out how to trigger actions when we start to draw the shapes by using onDrawCreated like 

       `    {{draw-control position="topright" showDrawingLayer=true 
            enableEditing=true 
             drawingFinishedAction='handleDrawingFinishedAction' 
             onDrawCreated=(action 'clicked')}}             `

and then in my component.js

    `clicked(e){
      console.log(e)                 }`

sry im new here can't figure out how to write codes in comments :P